# WebView keyboard React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

when I select a text field and the keyboard appears it spoils the layout, in case it raises the page but when the keyboard disappears the page continues raised

my WebView code:

```
<WebView
  renderLoading={this.renderLoading}
  startInLoadingState
  source={{uri: 'http://chatats.atsinformatica.com.br/chat/'}}
  style={{marginTop: 100}}
  scalesPageToFit={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  injectedJavaScript={`
  $('form:first').css('max-width', '100%');
  $('form:first').css('width', '100%');
  $('div:first').removeClass("wrapper");
  $('form:first').css('position', 'unset');
  $('form:first').css('padding-bottom', '100%');`}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `$('body').scrollTop({0});` in injectedJavaScript like follow

```
<WebView
  renderLoading={this.renderLoading}
  startInLoadingState
  source={{uri: 'http://chatats.atsinformatica.com.br/chat/'}}
  style={{marginTop: 100}}
  scalesPageToFit={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
  injectedJavaScript={`
  $('form:first').css('max-width', '100%');
  $('form:first').css('width', '100%');
  $('div:first').removeClass("wrapper");
  $('form:first').css('position', 'unset');
  $('form:first').css('padding-bottom', '100%');
  $('body').scrollTop({0});`
 }
/>
```

this solved your problem

[image]

You can also get Keyboard hide/show method in react native if you want to do some function on it

```
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow',(frames)=>{
      this.setState({keyboardSpace: 0});
    });
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide',(frames)=>{
      this.setState({keyboardSpace:0});
    });
```